# Safari HTML overflow-x not working

Tags: html, css, safari

This code does not only work on the Safari. How do I solve it?

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

`Overflow-x: hidden` does not work properly.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work properly?

Comment: please elaborate. Which version? What operating system? Define "not working"  Are you sure you don't need overflow-y? Overflow-x applies to horizontal, overflow-y applied to vertical

Comment: Please show us exactly what is not working with https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: It works everywhere, it just does not work in safari.

Comment: What version of safari, what OS? Please be more specific with your question - please read this: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According to the version which you use, try thoses css hack on this website : https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/css-hacks-for-safari-6-1-7-and-8-not-chrome/

It solve me lot of css problems.

Safari 7.1 and newer:

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {
  prop:val; 
}
```

/* Safari 10.1+ */

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {
    .safari_only { 
         prop:val;
     }
}}
```

/* Safari 6.1-10.0 (10.1 is the latest version of Safari at this time) */

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media {
    .safari_only {
        prop:val; 
    }
}}
```

/* Safari 6.1-7.0 */

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-color-index:0) {  
   .safari_only {(;
       prop:val; 
    );}
}
```

Comment: I do not know what version is. I want code to work properly on all browsers.

Comment: All browser don't react at the same way, this is why some css hack has been created. There is a lots of css hack for safari, firefox, IE, etc... Try to find your safari version, there is not another solution.

Comment: For your safari version :
1. Open your Safari browser by clicking on the Safari icon in the dock.
2. Click on Safari in your browser menu, located at the top of your screen.
3. A drop-down menu will now appear. Choose the option labeled About Safari.
4. A dialog box will now appear containing the browser's version number.